# conditional independence for a vector implies conditional independence for subvector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Let $X_1,X_2,C,Z$ be random variables.

Is it true that if $(X_1,X_2)\perp\!\!\perp Z\mid C$ then $X_1\perp\!\!\perp Z\mid C$?

I am reading a paper where this seams like it is implied, but cannot prove it. Just using Bayes and algebraically manipulating the equations doesn't directly lead to the result, but intuitively I think it is true: if some component of a vector was dependent on $Z$ then that would compromise the joint independent property for the whole vector...

Comment: If $U$ and $V$ are independent, then $f(U)$ and $g(V)$ are independent. I believe this also applies for conditional independence. In your case consider a function $f((X_1, X_2)) = X_1$.